# How to parse unknown key jsons using Moshi

Tags: java, android, retrofit, moshi

This is the example of JSON I am having

```
filter : [

    { category: [] } ,

    { sub-category: [] } ,

    { brand: [] } ,

    { color: [] } 
   ]
```

Note that the labels "category,subcategory..." may vary dynamically

How do I parse this JSON using Moshi ?

Comment: *How do I parse this JSON using Moshi ?* .. as usual ... obviously it's hard to guess what model you need after parsing

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Decode it as a `Map<String, Object>`. The map keys will be your JSON’s values. You can get that adapter like so:

```
Type map = Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, String.class, Object.class);
JsonAdapter<Map<String, Object>> adapter = moshi.adapter(map);
```

Comment: Getting stackoverflow exception

Comment: Add some context or reference

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin, Map<String, Object> from json:

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()    
val adapter = moshi.adapter<Map<String, Any>>(
            Types.newParameterizedType(Map::class.java, String::class.java, 
Object::class.java)
        )
    val yourMap =  adapter.fromJson(jsonFile)
```